How to access a html element in a PHP async function
I am writing a php where one of its function is to scrape data from internet. Thanks to Barmar, now I can display my scrapping result smoothly in my index.php file. Now, I want to update my scraping result to my database. But before that, I need to access to my scrapping result inside the  tag of id "result". Here is my php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>     
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>contacts.php</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="result">
    </div>

<?php
    $tz = 'Asia/Hong_Kong';
    $timestamp = time();
    $dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
    $dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp

    $eng_gov_html = 'https://www.info.gov.hk/gia/wr/' . substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),0, 4) . substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),5, 2) . '/'. substr($dt->format('Y/m/d'),8, 2) . '.htm';

    $rootFolder = dirname(__DIR__);
    require_once $rootFolder.'/Bulletin Translator/private/lib/vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');

    // Send an asynchronous request.
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', $chin_gov_html);
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) 
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        $body = (string) $response->getBody();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc->loadHTML($body);
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    

        $bulltin_name = $xpath->evaluate('//body/div/div/div/ul/li/a');
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";</script>';

        foreach($bulltin_name as $element)
        {
            //print_r($element->textContent."<br>");
            echo '<script>

                    for (i = 0; i <'. json_encode($element->textContent, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) .'.length; i++)
                    {
                        if ('. json_encode($element->textContent, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) .'.substring(i, i+1)!=" ")
                        {
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+='. json_encode($element->textContent, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) .'.substring(i, i+1);
                        }
                    }
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+="</br>";

                </script>';
        }

    
        echo '<script>
                    var total_bulletin_number = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML.split("天氣稿第").length - 1;
              </script>';

       $bulltin_url = $xpath->evaluate('//body/div/div/div/ul/li/a/@href');
       foreach($bulltin_url as $url)
       {
            echo '<script> document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+='. json_encode($url->textContent,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) .'+ "</br>"</script>';
        }

        echo '<script>
                  var content_array = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML.split("<br>");
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
              
                  for (c = total_bulletin_number - 1; c >= 0 ; c--)
                  {
                      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += content_array[c].substring(4, 7) + ": " + content_array[c].substring(9) + ", " + "https://www.info.gov.hk" + content_array[total_bulletin_number + c] + "</br>";
                  }
              
                  document.getElementById("result").removeChild(document.getElementById("result").lastElementChild);
                  content_array = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML.split("<br>");
              </script>';
    
        $result = $doc->getElementById('result')->textContent;
        print_r(explode("htm", $result));
    });

    $promise->wait();
?>

<?php

    // Some script here to upload the result to database...
    // Some script here to upload the result to database...
    // Some script here to upload the result to database...

?>
</body>
</html>

Now, I want to perform an operation in php like this as if in javascript:
var content_array = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML.split(".htm");
var content_arrary_length = content_array.length;

I try to add two lines at the end of my php script:
$result = $doc->getElementById('result')->textContent;
print_r(explode("htm", $result));
print_r(count(explode("htm", $result));

However, an error is returned:
Warning: Attempt to read property "textContent" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Bulletin Translator\index.php on line 118

What shall I do to asign a varibale to the result div within the same php file?

PHP cannot query the browser DOM. Use JS to extract what you need and send it as part of the request to the server.

The mix of server- and client-side coding you got going on here, makes it hard to tell, what you are actually talking about. I can't tell if you are talking about an element with the ID result that was contained in the actual HTML code you scraped - or if you are on a misguided trip to try and access the result of your JavaScript, that you are outputting there, in PHP again?

Sorry that I did not explain clearly. What I want to do is to take my php file as a tool to scrape data from internet directly and then upload them to my database directly. Since the raw data extracted is very messy, I summarized them by performing javascript encoded by php. Now I want to access to my scrapping result and asign them to a single php variable. But how shall I do?

So, are you scraping a third-party web page, spitting that out into a page under your control, using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, and you now want to get that as HTML?

Partially right, I am scraping a third-party web page and spitting and summarizing the result on the same php file, of course under my control. But now I want to assign my summarized result into a php variable (or multi variable) and then upload them to my database.

JavaScript is client sided, PHP is server sided. You can't mix and match them. Use PHP to handle the data. You can do that with something like Simple HTML DOM Parser, or any other library that can parse the HTML structure for you.

Understanding the difference between HTML and DOM is important. The latter, when inspected, happens to look like the former, but that is just for convenience. The former is static text, whereas the latter is dynamic and live. PHP does not have access to the DOM without using a DOM-aware parser. And some parsers say "DOM", but they just mean they build a DOM from the HTML, so you want to make sure your parser also supports JavaScript. Or, just call innerHTML on the body when done and send that to the server using normal JavaScript.
